# React-Native Customizing NavigationContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on converting a website, ReactJS, into a mobile app, React-Native. I want to customize the NavContainer but seem to be failing to do so. In the photo below, you will see the web application version of the app on the web built with ReactJs, and on the left, I am using React-Native and the following code below. Please advise!

Current React-Native Code

```
//Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

//Components
import Header from './components/header/Header';
//Screens
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Logout from './screens/Logout';

//Code
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const StackedScreens = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Dashboard'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={Logout}/>            
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['purple', 'gold']} style={styles.linearBGContainer}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StackedScreens/>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </LinearGradient>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  linearBGContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Demo
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this more and referred to the React Navigation Documentation. I found out that there is a way to [share common options across screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#sharing-common-options-across-screens). The "screenOptions" keyword was the best way to resolve my issue. For those who may fall into a similar issue, please navigate to the website, which mentions many more styling abilities.